# jScrollPane zero height on dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, jscrollpane

I have some content displayed as a list within a div. By default, the div is hidden, but becomes visible once it's parent has the class ".open":

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a>Options</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="menu-scroll">
            <ul>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

What happens is when I click the anchor within the list item, the list item receives the ".open" class, which enables displaying the ".dropdown-menu" . Now my problem is that I want that menu to have a max-height of say 200px, after which it should initialize the scroll. Considering that each of it's list items are 50px tall, we would have these scennarios:

- 2 list items, height of 100px, no scroll
- 3 list items, height of 150px, no scroll
- 4 list items, height of 200px, no scroll
- **5+ list items, height of over 200px and SCROLL**

This means I can't set a fixed height for .menu-scroll, since I want it to scale until reaching that height. What I do is set:

```
max-height: 200px;
height: auto;
```

It works perfect the first time I trigger the dropdowns but afterwards it renders everything wrong, like this:

[image: Wrong behaviour starts with second dropdown trigger]

**What I've tried:**

1. Initializing jScrollpane when clicking the anchor that toggles the .open class.
2. Initializing jScrollpane on document ready and only reinitializing the object when clicking the same anchor.

The results are the same everytime, as shown in the illustration above. I've searched the documentation, FAQ, StackOverflow, Google Groups but to no avail. Does anyone have any clues on this?

**EDIT:** This is the code I use to trigger the dropdown and initialize the scroll:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent('.dropdown').toggleClass('open').find('.dropdown-menu').jScrollPane();
});
```

What the .open class does is add

```
.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

to the otherwise hidden .dropdown-menu:

```
.dropdown.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get it right on first trigger and then it fails after that implies you have to check your script. Can you post your script here?